# Is there a way to find changes in SVN that have not been merged?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Let's say I've got an SVN repository with two branches: v1 and v2.  v2 was branched from v1 a few months ago, and work has gone forward on both branches.  Any changes to v1 should have been merged forward into v2, but it seems that some of them have been missed.

I know that merges are recorded by SVN, because you can see the information when you run Show Log in TortoiseSVN.  So does SVN (or the TortoiseSVN client) provide a way to say "look at all checkins to v1 since the branch point and find any that have not been merged forward"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

command line:

> svn mergeinfo source target --show-revs eligible

in TortoiseSVN you can see this in log when selecting what to merge (grey commits have been merged, black ones - not). Additionally there is a check box for hiding merged revisions.

Answer (score 1):

i think you'll find your answer [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html)..

OR you can use

```
svn diff http://server/svn/root/source-here@N http://server/svn/root/folder1/source-here@M
```

here N & M are two revisions to compare..

Comment: No, I'm not looking for differences between the two versions, because that would also catch all new work that was checked into v2 as false positives.  I'm specifically looking for exactly what I asked--a way to find v1 checkins that did not get merged forward into v2--to avoid having to run a diff and then manually filter out all the v2-specific changes.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `merge` dialog on the branch. Then in the second page of the merge wizard dialog, enter the url from `trunk` (or whatever url you use to merge changes from). Then click the `show log` button.

The log dialog now shows you all revisions you've already merge in gray, and those that haven't been merged yet in black.